# Changing State when Using Scala Concurrency

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency

I have a function in my Controller that takes user input, and then, using an infinite loop, queries a database and sends the object returned from the database to a webpage. This all works fine, except that I needed to introduce concurrency in order to both run this logic and render the webpage.

The code is given by:

```
 def getSearchResult = Action { request =>
    val search = request.queryString.get("searchInput").head.head

    val databaseSupport = new InteractWithDatabase(comm, db)

    val put = Future {
      while (true) {
        val data = databaseSupport.getFromDatabase(search)
        if (data.nonEmpty) {
          if (data.head.vendorId.equals(search)) {
            comm.communicator ! data.head
          }
        }
      }
    }
    Ok(views.html.singleElement.render)
  }
```

The issue arises when I want to call this again, but with a different input. Because the first thread is in an infinite loop, it never ceases to run and is still running even when I start the second thread. Therefore, both objects are being sent to the webpage at the same time in two separate threads.

How can I stop the first thread once I call this function again? Or, is there a better implementation of this whole idea so that I could do it without using multithreading?

**Note:** I tried removing the concurrency from this function (as multithreading has been the thing giving me all of these problems) and instead moving it to the web socket itself, but this posed problems as the web socket is connected to a router, and everything connects to the web socket through the router.

Comment: Did you try `if(nomore) break`?

Answer (score 0):

Try AsyncAction where you return a Future[Result] as a result. Make database call in side this result. E.g.(pseudo code),

```
def getSearchResult = AsyncAction { request =>
val search = request.queryString.get("searchInput").head.head

val databaseSupport = new InteractWithDatabase(comm, db)

Future {
  val data = databaseSupport.getFromDatabase(search)
  if (data.nonEmpty) {
    if (data.head.vendorId.equals(search)) {
      comm.communicator ! data.head // A
    }
  }
  Ok(views.html.singleElement.render)
}
```

}

Better if `databaseSupport.getFromDatabase(search)` returns a `Future` but that is a story for another day. The tricky part is to figure how to deal with Actor at "A". Just remember at the exit it must return `Future[Result]` result type.